# PHP ERROR : Notice: Undefined index: January in

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code for count news posted in month:

```
$months = array("January","February","March","April",
                "May","June","July","August","September","October",
                "November","December");
$mews = DB->fetch("SELECT id, YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) AS YEAR, 
                          MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) AS MONTH, 
                          COUNT(id) AS TOTAL 
                   FROM article
                   WHERE YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = 2014
                   GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH");

// Index article counts by month and year for easy lookup
$indexedNewsData = array();
foreach ($mews as $news) {
  $indexedNewsData[$news['MONTH']] = $news['TOTAL'];
}
// Then print output
foreach($mews AS $news){            

  foreach ($months as $month) {
    $total = intval($indexedNewsData[$month]);
    echo '<li>'.$month.' '.$total.'</li>';
  }     
}
```

But,for each month with `0` post I see This error :

`Notice: Undefined index: January in......`

how do can i fox this error?!

Demo : http://stackdemo.url.ph/test/

Source: http://stackdemo.url.ph/test/test

Comment: what is the content of $mews after the database call?

Comment: @amulous: Yes! Whats problem?

Comment: Try printing out $mews using var_dump and see if you are actually getting indexes like 'January'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialise your array properly.

```
$indexedNewsData = array();
foreach($months as $month) $indexedNewsData[$month] = 0;

foreach($mews as $news)
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This error told that you don't have key `January` within your `$indexedNewsData` array.

Fix is simple, you just have to make sure that `$indexedNewsData[$month]` is valid by checking:

```
$total = 0;
if( isset($indexedNewsData[$month]) ){
    $total = intval($indexedNewsData[$month]);
}
```

You can also fix it by initializing your array, as mentioned by @Niet in his answer.